# How to Save Data into an MySQL Database in PHP using Laravel and HTML

Tags: php, html, laravel, save

friend
i have a problem in my php code , i'm trying to Save data into mySQL Database using php and html and laravel, i have use the function to create this data and save it into MySQL Database but is not working , evry time i click the button to save data the view is return but the data is'nt save ? can any body help me please ,

My Route Code :

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

use App\Http\Controllers\ServicePaieController;


route::get('/',[ServicePaieController::class, 'index']);

Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/search', [ServicePaieController::class, 'searchDataAbsence'])->name('searchDataAbsence');

Route::post('/', [ServicePaieController::class,'storeAbsence'])->name('storeAbsence');

Route::middleware([
    'auth:sanctum',
    config('jetstream.auth_session'),
    'verified',
])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
        return view('dashboard');
    })->name('dashboard');
});
```

The Function Code in My Controller Code :

```
public function storeAbsence(Request $request) {

        $request->validate([
            'Matricule' => 'required',
            'Structure' => 'required',
            'NomPrenom' => 'required',
            'Abs_Periode' => 'required',
            'Abs_Mois' => 'required',
            'Abs_Exercice' => 'required',
            'Abs_jour_sp' => 'required',
            'Abs_Total_ap' => 'required',
            'Abs_Retenue_sp' => 'required',
            'Abs_jour_aes' => 'required',
            'Abs_Total_aes' => 'required',
            'Abs_Retenue_aes' => 'required',
            
        ]);

        Log::info('Your log message here');

        Absence::create([
            'Matricule' => $request->search,
            'Structure' => $request->nomStr,
            'NomPrenom' => $request->nomPer,
            'Abs_Periode' => $request->searchPeriode,
            'Abs_Mois' => "Décembre",
            'Abs_Exercice' => $request->searchExercice,
            'Abs_jour_sp' => $request->jour_sp,
            'Abs_Total_ap' => $request->total_sp,
            'Abs_Retenue_sp' => $request->retenue_sp,
            'Abs_jour_aes' => $request->jour_aes,
            'Abs_Total_aes' => $request->total_aes,
            'Abs_Retenue_aes' => $request->retenue_aes,
        ]);

        return redirect()->route('service_paie.service_paie_module')->with('success', "Absence data created successfully");
}
```

The HTML Code :

```
  <form class="font_size" id="addAbsenceForm" action="{{ route('storeAbsence') }}" method="post">
 @csrf 
       <!-- your form fields go here -->
      <div class="div_design">
       <div class="btn_design" role="group" aria-label="Actions">
                                        
    <input id="addAbsenceButton" class="btn_designBtn btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Enregistrer">
    </div>
      </div>
      </form>
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to save? There are no fields in your form, so nothing gets submitted

Comment: i want to save data , in my html code a have an input " name of student and dob " i want to save it into MySQL Database " Table Student " , i have add a button to submit this data , but is not working , the view is returning and data isnot save at all ?

Comment: this form is only for the button , i have tow other form , in this form i have the input for name and dob data

Comment: That makes no sense. You can only submit one form at once. That is a basic fact of html forms. The inputs and the button to submit need to all be within the same form

Comment: instead of separate form, why not create 1 single form then separate your information by div or section tag, You can also make it look like moving pages by adding next and prev button (but all it does is hide/show the prev/next section). That way, you would still have 1 form being submitted. Or just use ajax/axios to submit.

Answer (score 1):

In “storeAbsence” You do

```
request()->validate(…)
```

What happens is that it fails because not all required fields are there. Validate detects that and does

```
redirect()->back()->withErrors(…)
```

So add all the required fields to your form, display the errors to check for errors and your problem is fixed

Display of errors:

```
@error(‘inputname’)
<div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
@enderror
```

Comment: Thank yu , you help me , i have add an another form " saveForm" and i hide the first form "searchData" if the inputs of this form "SearchData" is fill hit values